# How to make file only accessible by JQuery .load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have written a php file, but I only want to have it accessible by JQuerys `.load` function.

So on the one page I use `.load` to include the content of the php file in another file, but when I directly move to the url of the php-file I load, it works as well, but I don't want that..

My Code for the `load` is:

```
$('#loader').load('secretFolder/secretFile.php');
```

whereas `loader` is a div for the content loaded. So when I no go to *example.com/secretFolder/secretFile.php* there should be an error, but it should the `.load` should still work.

I tried to set like a global variable on index.php and then check for it in `secretFile.php`, but that didn't work.

Please help...

Comment: How your `secrefFile.php` can be secret, if visitor will see it in your code??

Comment: I don't actually want to let user access this file by url, he only should be able to see it on the page where it is loaded by `.load`.

Comment: @FlorianSchüssler: No matter what you do, the user *will* be able to access the file if the user really wants to.  You're basically asking, "How do I let users access this information without letting users access this information?"  You can make it slightly more difficult for the user to go directly to that URL and *encourage* the user to stay within the prescribed UX.  But you can't "secure" the file from being accessed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check for AJAX request in your `secretFile.php`, so this should work:

```
if( empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) &&
strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) != "xmlhttprequest"){
    die("ERROR");
}
```

By this, you don't need to define any variables or something.

Comment: It is still possible for users to open it without using `.load()`.

Comment: But it's not accessible via the URL any more, and that's what he asked for, see _So when I no go to example.com/secretFolder/secretFile.php there should be an error, but it should the .load should still work._

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, so when I no go the URL, there comes up a error.

Comment: @FlorianSchüssler: `"Seems to work fine for me"` - It does work, and is pretty much your only option.  Just be aware that any user *can* still go directly to that file if they really want to.  This isn't actual security.  (But then, there is no actual security which does what you're asking.  So this is as good as it gets for your needs.)